# Catmull-Rom: spline and filter

Tags: interpolation, spline

On [this website](http://acko.net/blog/animate-your-way-to-glory-pt2/), the author gives this definition for Catmull-Rom splines (slide 10):

$$catmullRom(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
t^3 + 5t^2 + 8t + 4 & \text{if } -2 \le t \lt -1\\
-3t^3 - 5t^2 + 2 & \text{if } -1 \le t \lt 0\\
3t^3 - 5t^2 + 2 & \text{if } 0 \le t \lt 1\\
-t^3 + 5t^2 - 8t +4 & \text{if } 1 \le t \lt 2\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

An equivalent definition is found in *Fundamentals of Computer Graphics, Fourth Edition* on page 203, which refers to it as a "piecewise cubic filter". Indeed, the website says that while a single curve is filter, one can scale many curves by desired values, spread horizontally with even spacing, and sum them. This creates a single spline useful for keyframe animation.

However, [all](http://cdlab.berkeley.edu/Memos/CG/Pixar/spline77.pdf) [other](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/) [information](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/graphics/asst5/catmullRom.pdf) [I've](http://algorithmist.net/docs/catmullrom.pdf) [found](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/maths/catmull-rom-spline/) (five links) on Catmull-Rom splines begins with two points, and interpolates between them using the known derivatives at each point (or from two other points which are not interpolated). These sources usually specify a 4x4 matrix,

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1\\
2 & -5 & 4 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The top row (read right-to-left) matches the coefficents of $t^3$ above, but otherwise the values are not the same.

What is the relationship between these two constructions both referred to as Catmull-Rom splines? The first is a piecewise cubic filter applied to a single value, with interpolation emerging only from summing multiple such filters. The second seems to require (at least) two points in all cases.

Secondarily, I have not found any derivation for the piecewise function, and would like to know its origin (which I suspect, or hope, is related to the matrix).

Comment: Unfortunately the all-important page 600 is missing from the preview!

Comment: Amazon says 4th ed won't be released until January. The third ed doesn't seem to have an equivalent section, though the definition is on 204-205 (nearly the same as the 4th ed).